# iOS Push Notification open different app

Tags: ios

Can IOS push notifications open another app via its URL scheme (ie. SOMEAPP://someUrlScheme)?
I've looked through the documentation but haven't seen any mention of this.

Comment: did you find a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the notification bar I think it is not possible, but you can handle notification received event show a popup and launch another app on click event of that popup